# upgrade Android Marshmallow

Tags: android, upgrade

I have an old Android Wiko Ufeel, which I use as as a secondary tablet.
The hardware and battery are still usable, but most of  the apps
don't support Marshmallow any more.

I have tried to follow how to upgrade manually by following the links below, but I cannot follow them. They are not clear for me.

https://www.alphr.com/google/google-android/1001643/how-to-upgrade-from-android-lollipop-to-android-6-marshmallow/

https://www.easeus.com/android-data-recovery/upgrade-android-os-from-lollipop-to-6.0-marshmallow.html

Can I upgrade this with the Android studio by installing the standard Android?
Is there a link  which tells how?
I cannot find with google.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are on the right stack.

If I understood well, you're looking to upgrade the Firmware of your mobile phone.
Well, first of all, it is not possible to do that through Android Studio.

To uprgade a phone there is 3 ways to do that :

- The more secure one, as written on the website you linked : the OTA (Over The Air) updates :

  This method checks the compatible firmware with the actual one and tries to install the new Android version without deleting your data.

  It is possible to do that by going through "Settings => Phone Informations => Check for updates"

  If no update found, you may need to go to the 2nd option or 3rd option.

**Warning :** For the next methods, you loose the warranty, and once the new OS installed, all old data would be erased

- A less secure one (may damage the phone) : is to download manually an official firmware from a website who can provide the latest firmware Android version for your device.

  To do so, you may need to activate first developers option from the phone :

  - Go to Phone informations
  - Tap multiple times on the "Version Number", some phone they may need you to tap on the "Kernel version". You can check websites for that, and can see anyway a popup saying "need only 3 Taps to go"
  - Go to Settings again and activate developers options.
  - Enable the "OEM Unlock"

  After that, with a USB cable, activate the download mode on your phone, and (I may be old fashioned) I used Odin. You can follow the tutorial of the website who provides you the firmware on how to put it on Odin.
- The last method very insecure and instable one, is to look for a customized firmware. As reference, I used a lot LineageOS.

  For this method, you will need also to activate the OEM unlock (no need to say all the steps again), download the firmware, same thing about Odin, but the most difference is you will probably need to install the gapps (google apps) package manually (they are also in the tutorials).

Comment: Thanks. I wil try in the end of the week.
If it does not work, I put my phone away.
It is a bit shame because the hardware is OK.
(Might become slow with the newer systems)
I suppose in later Android versions the upgrade is easier.
I use mainly Apple IOS.